# C puzzle...How Can I pass variadic arguments into a macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions

I got stuck here...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DBG_LVL(lvl, stmt) \
do{ \
    if(lvl>1)  printf stmt; \
}while(0)

#define DBG_INFO(stmt)   DBG_LVL(1, stmt)
#define DBG_ERROR(stmt)  DBG_LVL(2, stmt)


int main()
{
    DBG_INFO(("hello, %s!\n", "world"));
    DBG_ERROR(("crazy, %s!\n", "world"));
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the code above uses macros like "DBG_INFO" or "DBG_ERROR" to control debug information level.

Now for some reason, I have to replace `DBG_LVL()` with a new function.

```
void myprint(int lvl, const char * format, ...);
```

The only difference is the debug level is taken as its fisrt parameter. 
I was thinking:

```
#define DBG_LVL(lvl, stmt) myprint(lvl, stmt)
```

Of course it failed, because **the "stmt" expression includes parentheses around**.
Then I googled around trying to find a way to strip the parentheses, seems there's nothing could help.
I also tried some tricks to pass parameters into "stmt", still failed... :(

Can you help me?

Comment: Always google for what you want, not what you think you want. Same goes for asking people questions.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Maybe I should not put in too much subjective opinions when asking questions...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
# define EXPAND_ARGS(...) __VA_ARGS__
# define DBG_LVL(lvl, stmt) myprint(lvl, EXPAND_ARGS stmt);
```

Comment: Yes! It works. This trick is awesome!
actually I studied **__VA_ARGS__** for a while, but i did't notice it can be used this way...
even worse, i tried `#define xx((stmt)) stmt`, haha, compiler complained a lot.....

Answer (score 2):

Don't write this as a macro.

Write instead an ordinary varargs function:

```
void DBG_LVL(int level, char *fmt, ...)
{
    if (level < 1) return;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    vaprintf(fmt, args);

    va_end(args);
}
```

For `myprint()`, define a similar `vamyprint(int lvl, const char *format, va_list ap)` as well, and forward the same way.

Comment: Yes, that's one way. Thanks. :)
but there's some difficulties, because these macros "DBG_INFO" "DBG_ERROR" were widely used in projects, over 20 thousands files... I can't just update all these projects for this reason.